# Why is NSIndexPath indexPathForItem returning an invalid path?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm having an issue where the following function

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:0]
```

sometimes returns an NSIndexPath object that has the following description:

```
<NSIndexPath: 0x7a32c0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2147483648}
```

Obviously that's an invalid path, but I can't find any source that says why the function would be returning such a path. If I cancel the operation and run the same line of code a few moments later, it returns a correct value.

The incorrect value being returned is seemingly random, so I'm trying to find out what would cause it to return such a value. The documentation states that it would return nil if there is no valid index path.

Comment: 2147483648  is exactly 2^31. What is `item`?

Comment: I noticed that as well, but I have no idea why it would return that value. `item` is an index to an item in my `UICollectionView`. I have checked that the index is a valid index even in the cases where the function returns an incorrect value.

Comment: How have you checked that? I don't know what documentation you read, but `-[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:inSection:]` never returns nil — it just puts the two numbers you give it into an index path object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path is not invalid. Your provided `item` index is.

I'll give you a hint. Try to run this code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:NSNotFound inSection:0]);
```

If you still have trouble finding the problem, have a look at how `item` is calculated. There's probably some code like...

```
NSUInteger item = [someArray indexOfObject:someObject];
```

... where the `NSNotFound` value signals a missing object.

Comment: Alright, I'll look into it further, thanks for the tip. I'll accept this answer if it turns out to be the case.